# Copy/Commit locally unversioned file to SVN versioned file via CI

Tags: shell, svn, continuous-integration

I'm generatin a file with Jenkins that I want to commit in SVN.

The produced file is not it not versioned localy but is meant to replace one that is on SVN.
To achive that purpose I'm running this commands

```
svn delete <URL to file>
svn import <Local file path> <URL to file>
```

I works, but I lose the log history of the file

**There is any way can do this without losing the log history?**

I'm trying to commit the file without much success. Does commit even make sense?

The best I could produce was this:

```
>svn commit --force-log -F <Local file path> <SVN URL path to folder of the file> --username [*******] --password [*******] 
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help commit' for more information
svn: E205000: Commit targets must be local paths
svn: E205000: <SVN URL path to folder of the file> is not a local path
```

I'm guiding myself with this but without much success [SVN CI documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `svn delete` the file, this is when the history is lost. Instead, you should get the versioned file locally, change it, then commit it. For that, you need to check out the directory containing the versioned file first.

Assuming the URL of the file you want to update is `<URL_path>/<file>`, and your local file is `<local_file>`, you can do:

```
svn checkout <URL_path> foo
cp -f <local_file> foo/<file>
svn commit foo/<file> -m "commit message"
```